# Convert/get varchar variable to YYYYMM

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, type-conversion

I have 4 CTE's in this table and the third one contains a DATETIME converted to VARCHAR (with format based on the requirement) as `startDate` in `DD/MM/YYYY` format. The last cte does calculations based on the data generated and one of the columns needs to store `YYYYMM` date based on `startDate`.

The problem it's getting the year and the month from this converted DATETIME, using convert() it shows this:

```
IDPER
-------
01/01/ --DD/MM/
```

These 2 show `YYYYMM` correctly when startDate isn't converted:

```
Select *, left(convert(nvarchar(6),new_ini,112),6) as IDPER from table

Select *, convert(nvarchar(6),new_ini,112) as IDPER from table
```

How could I get `YYYYMM` format having `startDate` converted? Or what could be a more smart approach to the requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My way would be slightly different

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(6), CONVERT(DATE, new_ini, 103), 112);
```

Here, I first converted it to date and then formatted to YYYYMMDD and taken 6 chars only

Answer (score 1):

If you have a string in the format DD/MM/YYYY and you want YYYYMM, then use string operations:

```
select right(new_ini, 4) + substring(new_ini, 4, 2)
```

You should be storing date values as `date`s or a related type, not as string.  But given that you have already stored this as a string, string operations can do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

declare `@date DATE = GETDATE();`

```
select REPLACE(LEFT(CONVERT(DATE,@date,112),8),'-','')  -- 1st approach

select FORMAT(@date,'yyyyMM') --2nd approach
```